# How to uninstall r-essentials using conda?

Tags: r, kernel, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

Recently, I installed `r-essentials` using `conda` command: `conda install -c r r-essentials` as it is described in this url: https://anaconda.org/r/r-essentials. However, when I try to run a new R Kernel, ii fails according to this error:

```
...Anaconda3\R/bin/x64/Rterm.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I want to remove R folder that was created after installation But I cannot find a way to remove that folder.

I tried:

```
conda uninstall r-essentials
```

Then:

```
conda remove R
```

Last one, according to this answer on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/57zh19/help_removing_anaconda_r_and_using_system_r_with/

Any of those have removed *R folder*.

Is there an specific command to remove it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

r-essentials is a metapackage, and therefore cannot be uninstalled this way.

Try running `conda uninstall r-base` to uninstall Anaconda R, and then install R regularly. Then, run `which R` to make sure that it works. You should now see the path to the system R, instead of the Anaconda R.

I recommend then following the instructions here - this installation worked for me: http://irkernel.github.io/.

Comment: Thanks, Oren. It works greta, ans thanks for the tip on how to install kernel again.

Comment: This fixed the problem where different versions of R were installed in my computer. The one on conda env was not working properly (could not import tidyverse library) and the version in usr/local/bin was working. After uninstalling the one from the conda env, automatically the env used R from usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 4):

to remove r packages, run the conda prompt as an administrator. then execute this command
conda remove r-*

Comment: Awesome! `*` as wild card does not appear to be documented, nice find

Comment: `conda remove "r-*"` for zsh

Answer (score 1):

`conda uninstall r-base` >> jupyter notebook has something file and button

I think you can try  `$conda list | grep r` // see r package files

`$conda uninstall r-*` // delete all r package

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: The first command `$conda list | grep r` should be `conda list | grep r-`. The final `-` is vital. You should still check what the second command returns as it will not uniquely identify R packages. For example, the `navigator-updater` Python package would fall into the `r-` search criterion. This can be overcome by using the `^` begins with expression:  `conda list | grep ^r-`.