# Remove Anaconda R and use system R

Tags: r, anaconda

I have partially removed Anaconda R. Base R now runs by default. However, when I install *some* R packages with base R install they fail. I think they are failing because of an old symbolic link to anaconda.

I want to remove Anaconda R because there are too many package version conflicts.

I am using Linux Mint 19 (i.e. Ubuntu 18.04).

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48482778/3371413) to remove Anaconda R. Thus, I did:

1. `conda uninstall r-base`
2. `conda uninstall r-*`

Now `which R` returns `/usr/bin/R`. If I load R from the linux command line using `R` and then run `version` in R I get:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

If I try to install a package such as `install.packages("forecast")` (this happens for any of the below packages that fails `quadprog`, `fracdiff` etc) then I get the following error message:

```
> install.packages("forecast")
Installing package into ‘/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘quadprog’, ‘fracdiff’, ‘tseries’, ‘RcppArmadillo’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/quadprog_1.5-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 35925 bytes (35 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 35 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/fracdiff_1.4-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 57636 bytes (56 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 56 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tseries_0.10-47.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 164796 bytes (160 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 160 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.9.700.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1366153 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/forecast_8.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 829958 bytes (810 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 810 KB

* installing *source* package ‘quadprog’ ...
** package ‘quadprog’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility=hidden -fpic -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -msse2 -mfpmath=sse   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c aind.f -o aind.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility=hidden -fpic -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -msse2 -mfpmath=sse   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c solve.QP.compact.f -o solve.QP.compact.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility=hidden -fpic -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -msse2 -mfpmath=sse   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c solve.QP.f -o solve.QP.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility=hidden -fpic -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -msse2 -mfpmath=sse   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c util.f -o util.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o quadprog.so aind.o init.o solve.QP.compact.o solve.QP.o util.o -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/home/sav/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: quadprog.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quadprog’
* removing ‘/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/quadprog’
* installing *source* package ‘fracdiff’ ...
** package ‘fracdiff’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fdcore.c -o fdcore.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fdgam.c -o fdgam.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fdhess.c -o fdhess.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fdmin.c -o fdmin.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fdsim.c -o fdsim.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c pmult.c -o pmult.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o fracdiff.so fdcore.o fdgam.o fdhess.o fdmin.o fdsim.o init.o pmult.o -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/home/sav/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: fracdiff.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fracdiff’
* removing ‘/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/fracdiff’
* installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++11 -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ version is sufficient... yes, with OpenMP as version 7.2.0
checking for macOS... checking LAPACK_LIBS... system LAPACK found
checking for OpenMP... found and suitable
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating inst/include/RcppArmadilloConfigGenerated.h
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -fopenmp -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/home/sav/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/home/sav/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RcppArmadillo’
ERROR: dependency ‘quadprog’ is not available for package ‘tseries’
* removing ‘/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/tseries’
ERROR: dependencies ‘fracdiff’, ‘tseries’, ‘RcppArmadillo’ are not available for package ‘forecast’
* removing ‘/home/sav/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/forecast’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpS4CVTK/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘quadprog’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘fracdiff’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘tseries’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status
```

From the error code I can identify that problems start to occur with the `gcc` compiler. It looks like my base R installation is trying to access binaries in an `anaconda3` folder at `/home/sav/anaconda3/bin/`:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o quadprog.so aind.o init.o solve.QP.compact.o solve.QP.o util.o -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/home/sav/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note I do not want to remove the anaconda3 folder as it contains important Python packages.

Also the problem is not specific to `forecast` package. If I go for `RcppArmadillo` I get similar errors. The culprit line is

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -fopenmp -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/home/sav/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/home/sav/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
```

My `~/.bashrc` contains the following lines

```sh
# added by Anaconda3 installer
# export PATH="/home/sav/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/sav/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
. /home/sav/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Comment: Neither of these related posts on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609405/remove-anaconda-r-from-ubuntu) or [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/57zh19/help_removing_anaconda_r_and_using_system_r_with/) help with this problem.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install r-cran-forecast`... try that.

Comment: That command returns an error `E: Unable to locate package r-cran-forecast`.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using ubuntu. Maybe that's wrong. Here's how to add the repository to get to r-cran-foo packages... https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: The error shows that `ld` can't find `liblapack` and `libblas`. Are you sure those are installed? Check `ldconfig -p | grep -E "lib(blas|lapack)"`

Comment: The command `ldconfig -p | grep -E "lib(blas|lapack)"` returns the following
 `liblapack.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3
 liblapack.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so
 libblas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3
 libblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so`

Comment: Here is a related problem: https://askubuntu.com/q/1163685/174320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial Solution (use with caution)**

If I comment out the final two lines of script that Anaconda has added to my `~/.bashrc` as follows:

```
# added by Anaconda3 installer
# export PATH="/home/sav/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 installer
# export PATH="/home/sav/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
# . /home/sav/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Then restart my computer. It solves the problem that R tries to use the `gcc` compiler from Anaconda. The result is that I can install all of the R packages that were previously failing.

My concern is that this is a brutish solution. I think commenting out the above lines in my `~/.bashrc` will *break* Ananconda in other ways and I still want to use Anaconda with Python say, just not R.

Comment: So, you're actually doing the right thing: [since Conda v4.4 it has been recommended](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell) to no longer export Anaconda/Miniconda to `PATH`. Now, since Conda v4.6 you can use `conda init` to set up the recommended configuration that instead defines a `conda` shell function, and should avoid issues like you were having.

Comment: Good then this should solve https://askubuntu.com/q/1163685/174320 too. (I have to wait until tomorrow to accept the answer.)